# Activity creation in Salesforce Lightning for Internal and Outbound Call

Tags: lightning, opencti

We have a CRM connector build using open cti APIs. I am passing some parameters in saveLog() method as follow-

`sforce.opencti.saveLog({value: 
{
 entityApiName: 'Task', 
WhoId: whoID, 
WhatID: whoID, 
Subject: subject, 
CallType: calltype, 
Description: description, 
Priority: 'Normal',
Status: 'Completed', 
CallDurationInSeconds: talktime,
 ActivityDate: dueDate
}, callback: callbackmethod})
}`

Its working fine when some matching record is found, i.e value of 'WhoId' is not null or undefined. I am getting following error in response.

> code : "GENERIC_ERROR"
>   description
>   :
>   " An error occurred while calling the API method We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask your administrator for help.. Error: ."

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the contact doesn't exist in your system, the WhoId won't exist. You'll need to create a new contact if the `WhoId == null` before you can create the Task. Depending on the rest of your code, you could also surround that with a try-catch block.